# How to parse a collection's sub-object to find a unique result from many possibilities?

Tags: meteor

In my user's schema, I have a `TokAuth` Array with `token` sub-objects (like multiple mails addresses).

So in a method, when I search the tokens in the current user :

```
var id = Meteor.userId();
var usercurrent = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id}, {fields: {"TokAuth": 1}});
var userToken = usercurrent.TokAuth.token;
```

I got in `console.log(userToken)`

```
[ 'fyAyXkXYrQdAlNpjuQfJ8RLU2TpfVGLnptlBs-m1h7xk',
I20170224-20:36:23.202(1)?   'YTwtUbhNTgiEfzFbJq7mESnOoOHeLYxWlqEeJJIG_GiV',
I20170224-20:36:23.206(1)?   'ViA4ydDITJtHDi2c_sArkNtpRYTjFqGL1ju2v00_-rFJ',
I20170224-20:36:23.206(1)?   '51ImZcxRADLJr-FPCUL7EFGnTZYjHSZk3XxdqtBV2_fd',
I20170224-20:36:23.207(1)?   'S5aEvqjJ5zTUJqLFCPY1aZ1ZhsQppZTJtYKULM9aS2B3',
I20170224-20:36:23.207(1)?   'mhBs3oxHf2SxZfu2vCZhtiyPfg25fKMY8bKMZD8fx6IG',
I20170224-20:36:23.207(1)?   '-rv0FiP-lxoqe8INyCJASV6rZpbgy3euEqB9sO9HsZSV',
I20170224-20:36:23.207(1)?   'zacr6_VBjHTsArov1LmQyZFLwI40fx4J7sygpLosTrli' ]
```

Beside, I've got a `var` who is equal to the last token in the `userToken` sub-object (that's of course expected : not to be *the last one*, but to be in the sub-object).

```
console.log (editAuth);
zacr6_VBjHTsArov1LmQyZFLwI40fx4J7sygpLosTrli
```

So how can I parse `userToken` to find a match with `editAuth`? If `userToken` was just a `String`, it will be simple but here...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are storing all the tokens as an array as opposed to just updating a single string each time?

That aside, you can check if an array contains a value by using the handy underscore function `_.contains`

Example:

```
_.contains( userToken, editAuth ); //returns true or false
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you are simply trying to search for a string within an array of strings.  @Sean already provided one solution.

If you are using the meteor ecmascript package then you can just simply use the native [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```
userToken.includes(editAuth);
```

On a side note, after using ECMAScript 2015+ for some time now, I find that I can use the native API for almost everything that I used to use underscore or lodash for.  Check it out!

Comment: Good suggestion, I should probably stop using underscore as often now that I actually understand JavaScript!